# Risks of cycling across minefield

Tags: bicycles, africa, angola

I am planning an off-road cycling trip in Angola. What happens if a bicycle is ridden over a land mine? Will it detonate? Will it result in injury, death or bicycle damage? Does it depend on the type of landmine?

Comment: I vote to close this as it is not about travel; but in short, don't ride on mines.

Comment: This is impossible to answer. A mine might detonate under the weight of a bicycle and rider, or it might not. The detonation might injure or kill you, and might damage or destroy your bicycle. It'd depend on the type of mine, how artfully it was emplaced, the nature of the soil, whether the mine operates as designed, and probably other factors. Without knowing all those things, the best anyone can say is... _maybe_ .

Comment: As some mines detonate when kids step on them, I would NEVER risk walking or cycling over them. Rats are being trained to find them, as their weight is deemed too small to be dangerous.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about travel but about weapon risks.

Comment: I'm not answering this landmine.

Comment: I strongly disagree with those who claim that this question is not about travel.  Whatever this question's problems may be, that is not one of them.  I am voting to reopen.  Fab: you might have a better reception if you ask about the prevalence of land mines in Angola and the likelihood of encountering them during an off-road cycling trip (without warning: signed minefields can be avoided).  I have not been to Angola, but I've spent a lot of time in Bosnia, and it is certainly the case that there are places in Bosnia where one can pursue outdoor activities safely and places where one cannot.